# MissingSecurityHeader error for S3 bucket ACL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following s3 bucket defined:

```
module "bucket" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws"
  version = "3.1.0"

  bucket = local.test-bucket-name
  acl    = null

  grant = [{
    type       = "CanonicalUser"
    permission = "FULL_CONTROL"
    id         =  data.aws_canonical_user_id.current.id
    }, {
    type       = "CanonicalUser"
    permission = "FULL_CONTROL"
    id         = data.aws_cloudfront_log_delivery_canonical_user_id.cloudfront.id
    }
  ]
  object_ownership = "BucketOwnerPreferred"
}
```

But when I try to `terraform apply` this, I get the error:

> Error: error updating S3 bucket ACL (logs,private): MissingSecurityHeader: Your request was missing a required header status code: 400

This error message is not very specific. Am I missing some type of header?

Comment: Based on the module code, I think `acl = null` has to be actually `acl = "null"`: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-s3-bucket/blob/master/main.tf#L44.

Comment: @MarkoE - really good idea I thought that would fix it but alas still getting the same cryptic error :(

Comment: have you tried leaving out the variable since you don't need it ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I hit this when updating the AWS provider from 4.x to 5.3.0 where some buckets previously had an ACL of `private` and it was wanting to set them to `null`, like the previous answer.

However, the issue for me was just transitive - running `terraform apply` a second time came back `No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration`. I didn't need to modify any ACLs manually.

A bug report has been opened with the AWS provider to avoid the need to do `terraform apply` a second time. See here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/31633

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same issue.
I was trying to update an ACL on a bucket which had previously had private set as the ACL and then modifying my terraform code to match manually created entries on the ACL that someone had done via the GUI.

To get it working for me, I removed one of the ACL entries from the S3 bucket manually of which I was trying to add to the bucket and then re-ran the terraform and it worked without an error

I see the same error in cloudtrail also.

Its like you cant set private acl to null without adding an ACL entry

Comment: Thanks this helped me as well, but is there a long term solution to this?